# Adding a value to an existing row/column in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, math

I have a simple dataframe and I want to dynamically do arithmetic at a given row/col

If the dataframe look like this:

```
Bin    Count

A      21

B      18

C      22

D      24
```

I want to add 6 to the "Count" for "Bin D" making it equal to 30. Is there a way to simply add a number to whatever is in that col/row?

Thanks, I am sure there is a very simple answer to this but I am new to pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.loc[df.Bins=='D', 'Count'] += 6
```